# Tab sequence in dynamic forms

Tags: forms, keyboard

This question is about usable tab sequences in dynamic forms. Is it possible to exclude conditional fields from the tab sequence when they are hidden, and include them when they are visible? Assume that the conditional fields are in the middle of the form, not at the end.

What I'm hoping to prevent is the tab sequence jumping around in unpredictable ways (non-linearly) and getting lost (jumping to hidden fields).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible.

The actual implementation may vary depending on the platform. In HTML/CSS for example, you can set `visibility: hidden` or `disabled: disabled` and the tab index will be skipped automatically.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Does it alos work if the tab sequence is explicitly defined (tabindex)?

Comment: Yes, the focus will jump to the next higher tabindex that is not hidden or disabled.